# Convert multiple SQL Server queries into one

Tags: sql-server

I have a page that ask of users opinion about a topic. Their responses are then saved into a table. What I want to do is to check how many users selected an option 1,2,3 and 4.

What I have now are multiple T-SQL queries that run successfully but I believe there is a simplified version of the code I have written. I would be grateful if someone can simplify my queries into one single query. Thank you.

here is sample of data in the database table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU0W3.png)

```
$sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(CO) FROM GnAppItms WHERE CO='1' AND MountID='".$mountID."'";
$stmt4 = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql4);
$row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt4);

$sql5="SELECT COUNT(CO) FROM GnAppItms WHERE CO='2' AND MountID='".$mountID."'";
$stmt5=sqlsrv_query($conn2,$sql5);
$row5=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt5);

$sql6="SELECT COUNT(CO) FROM GnAppItms WHERE CO='3' AND MountID='".$mountID."'";
$stmt6=sqlsrv_query($conn2,$sql6);
$row6=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt6);

$sql7="SELECT COUNT(CO) FROM GnAppItms WHERE CO='4' AND MountID='".$mountID."'";
$stmt7=sqlsrv_query($conn2,$sql7);
$row7=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt7);
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT CO, COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY CO) FROM GnAppItms WHERE CO in ('1', '2', '3', '4') AND MountID='".$mountID."'` ought to do it...

Comment: It can also be done with a GROUP BY clause, if you'd care to google and learn about this basic approach.

Comment: @JoeMalpass i tried your answer and it worked for $row[0] thus option 1 where only one person chose that option. but for $row[3] which is option 4 with two people choosing that option, it return null....

Comment: TBH, I can't see how $row[n] relates to your select statement at all. While we're happy to help when you get stuck, it is generally expected that users show how *they* have attempted to solve their problem first, and examples of both the input data and the expected results. See [Ask] and [Writing The Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. i have edited the question...please if you examine my queries well, you could see i access the number of people who choose a particular option, that way i can output the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using group by in sql server

example :

```
create table a
(id int,
 mountid nvarchar(100),
 co int,
)

insert into a values (1,'aa',1)
insert into a values (2,'aa',2)
insert into a values (3,'aa',1)
insert into a values (4,'aa',2)
insert into a values (5,'aa',3)
```

Query

```
select co,count(co)as countofco from a 
where mountid='aa'
group by 
co
```

result

```
co  countofco
1   2
2   2
3   1
```

Note : Beware of SQL injection when you are writing a sql query, so always use parametrized query. You can edit the above example code and make it as a parametrized query for preventing sql injection

Comment: thanks @Arunprasanth KV very for your help. Please can i store each of the result set into a variable because i want display into in a formatted table

Comment: @BigPee yes you can do that, which language you are used ? C#,vb ,php which one ?